# How to correctly import python modules when the program runs in visual studio code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a `my_program.py` python script.

Inside this script, I can import the class in `utils/my_util.py` by starting the script with `python -m foo.my_program`.

Here's the content of `my_program.py`

```
from utils.my_util import Util

u = Util()
```

But when I press `Start Debugging` button for `foo/my_program.py` in visual studio code, it generates the following error.

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'utils'
  File "/Users/my_name/debug/python_proj/foo/my_program.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils.my_util import Util
```

How can I run `python -m foo.my_program` in visual studio code?

I think there's something in `.vscode/launch.json` that I can configure to make the program run correctly.

I've tried setting `"cwd"` to [`"${workspaceFolder}"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference). But this doesn't work.

Here's the folder structure of my scripts.

```
.
├── foo
│   └── my_program.py
└── utils
    └── my_util.py
```

Comment: For that to work, the "current directory" has to be `.../debug/python_proj`.  VSCode is probably starting in `.../debug/python_proj/foo`.  You can change that in your debug configuration, or you can append the proper path to `sys.path` before you do the import.

Comment: Have you tried `from .. utils import my_util`

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan, I got the code from my ex-colleague. I want to understand how the code works before modifying it.

Comment: `from .. utils import my_util` creates `attempted relative import with no known parent package` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding the following parameters under `"configurations"` of `.vscode/launch.json` works.

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
"env": {
    "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

According to [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), `${workspaceFolder}` means "the path of the folder opened in VS Code".

And [this document](https://tutorialslink.com/Articles/What-is-Python-path/1422) says that `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable which the user can set to add additional directories that the user wants Python to add to the sys. path directory list.

So Adding `${workspaceFolder}` to `PYTHONPATH` means python will search `${workspaceFolder}` folder when it runs `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Except in the launch.json file, you can also:

Add this in the settings.json file, it will affects the action which run within the terminal, such as `Run Python File in Terminal`:

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
      "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
  },
```

Or, create a `.env` file and added this to it:

```
PYTHONPATH={some path to the parent folder of the module which you want to import, such as workspaceFolder}
```

and you can point the `.env` file manually through `"python.envFile"` in the settings.json or `"envFile"` in the launch.json, and `"envFile"` will overwrite `"python.envFile"`.